# GIT is working painfully slow

Tags: macos, mac, git

[This is a link to a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKXSjx20sGo&feature=youtu.be) in which you can see how slow it works....

It takes more than 3 minutes to perform a `git status` command.

I've tried updating GIT to the latest version as well as executing the garbage collector (`git gc---aggressive`) but nothing gets better.

Any help on how to fix it would be very appreciated.

Comment: This depends on the repository size and storage medium (e.g. HDD). It may take some time at first run.

Comment: See: [How can I debug git/git-shell related problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6178401/55075)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using stock git or git from Homebrew?
If it's from Homebrew, use the stock git may improve the performance

```
brew unlink git
```

Here's the original article I found online: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2019/git-2201-super-slow-on-macos-mojave-on-my-work-mac

Comment: this helped me!